# Magento 2 override the cutomer account loginpost controller

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-group, magento2.1.5, redirection

I am trying to overriding the below class in my custom module:

**vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost.php**

For overriding this I have created the **Plugin** file as per the below Magento 2 official reference:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

I have created the **app/code/Vendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="MyCucomtLoginAccountLoginPost" type="Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now, I have written the below is **aroundExecute** method to achieve my customization:

**app\code\Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Customer**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Customer;

class LoginPost
{
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {   
        //echo 'here'; die;
        if (isset($login['press_room_page'])) {
            $custom_redirect=true;
            }
        if (isset($login['press_room_page']) && $custom_redirect) {

            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('mycustomlogin/index');
            return $resultRedirect; 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The above code is working fine when I am print something "here" it means the file is override successfully.

Now I am adding my logic in the **execute** method below is original file of vendor which I have edited for testing purpose to check the logic work or not:

**vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Customer\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{   
    /** @var AccountManagementInterface */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /** @var Validator */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var AccountRedirect
     */
    protected $accountRedirect;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private $cookieMetadataManager;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param CustomerUrl $customerHelperData
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        CustomerUrl $customerHelperData,
        Validator $formKeyValidator,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->customerUrl = $customerHelperData;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Login post action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        

            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                    if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                        $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                        $metadata->setPath('/');
                        $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
                    }
                    $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                    if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
                        $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                        // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
                        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
                        return $resultRedirect;
                    }
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                        'This account is not confirmed. <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                        $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                    $message = __(
                        'The account is locked. Please wait and try again or contact %1.',
                        $this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('contact/email/recipient_email')
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    if (isset($login['my_custom_page'])) {
                        $custom_redirect=true;
                    }
                    $message = __('Invalid login or password.');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // PA DSS violation: throwing or logging an exception here can disclose customer password
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        __('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.')
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }
        if (isset($login['my_custom_page']) && $custom_redirect) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('mycustomlogin/index');
            return $resultRedirect; 
        }
        return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
    }
}
```

Please see the below image to better understand what I have added my logic:

[image]

Please see below is second image to written logic for redirect user to again if they enter wrong username or password:[image]

**Below is the main moto for override the controller:**

I have created the custom login page for specific customer group, they will login from the custom design page, so I have created the **mycustomlogin.phtml** in my module like: `app\code\Vendor\MyModule\view\frontend\templates\mycustomlogin.phtml` and passed the hidden input field value in the form for check where user had posted the form. I have get the hidden input value in `AuthenticationException $e` to check. if user have posted the form from custom design.

Anyone can suggest me how I can add my logic into the **Plugin** file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to rewrite the customer loginPost plugin file as per the below

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MYMODULENAME\Plugin\Customer;

class LoginPost
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_response = $context->getResponse();
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
        $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
    }

    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $proceed)
    {           
        $login =  $this->_request->getPost('login');     
        $custom_redirect= false;

        $returnValue = $proceed();            

        if (isset($login['press_room_page'])) {
            $custom_redirect=true;
        }
        if (isset($login['press_room_page']) && $custom_redirect) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('mycustomlogin/index');
            return $resultRedirect; 
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE and thanks for your contribution, hope it helps the question author. A *good* answer that educates the reader would also explain what the mistakes were. What did you change to make the code work and why?

Comment: I have called the parent controller execute method.
$returnValue = $proceed();

Comment: superb lavanya - its working perfectly

Comment: It's very simple and working perfectly in all cases, I have tested it will both cases for custom login and default login. It's working fine.

Comment: Sure @mageDev0688

Comment: I need to check some custom attribute called status enabled or disabled, if status is disabled i need to show message account is disabled, this can be done?

Comment: @lavanya, can we check whether the customer is logged in with correct password or not with $proceed?

Answer (score 2):

According to @lavanya answer, the best way indeed is to use the plugin interceptor, I wanted to add a full answer and in more clean.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="CustomerLoginRedirectPlugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\LoginPost" disabled="false" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/LoginPost.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class LoginPost
{
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $url;
    protected $_request;
    protected $_response;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        UrlInterface $url,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory

    )
    {
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_response = $context->getResponse();
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, \Closure $proceed) {
        /*Execute code before the original function*/
        $login =  $this->_request->getPost('login');     
        //$username = $login['username']; to retrieve the user name for exemple.
        $custom_redirect= false;
        if (isset($login['press_room_page'])) {
            $custom_redirect=true;
        }

        $resultProceed = $proceed(); // Original function
        /*Execute code after the original function*/
        if ($custom_redirect) {
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('router/controllerfolder/controllername/'));
            return $result;
        }

        return $resultProceed;
    }
}
```

<sup>**it could help someone.**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use after execute plugin and after that you can check either customer is login or not if not than you can redirect to your press page url

```
namespace Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Customer;

class LoginPost
{
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,$result)
    {   
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
       if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
          // redirect to press page
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to check first if they entered wrong login details, then? Also, If they have entered the wrong detail then they will automatically redirect on the default magento login page. So, that's why I want to override the `Loginpost.php` class? I just want to if they have filled the login details on my custom login page than I want to show the error message on `Invalid Username or Password` on my custom login page not on the default login page.

Comment: @Ankit could you please help me out this issue. This is not correct answer of the above question.

Comment: please see the above answer, what I want.