# Magento 2: Check the status before customer login

Tags: magento2, login

I have to add a user is active or not check before the user login for any place in my site. How can I do it? I mean which module or function need to override in my site.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override LoginPost Controller and in it's execute function do your code,
In this controller you will get all the customer information before login, you can check customer is active or not then return.
To override follow this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179731/81151

Comment: He doesn't want to check if customer is logged in or not, he wants to check if customer status is active or not before login

Comment: so you mean i need to overide the **isLoggedIn** function?

Comment: @Shoaib Munir Yes, i need check as per your comment.

Comment: @AKM please check the updated answer