# How to add login form to home page in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3.4, customer-login

I had added the login form in the home page using the block, i inherited the block to home cms page the form is also viewing correctly but when iam using invalid credentials the page is redirected to default login page and showing the error i want to display all kind of error in cms page login section and want avoid the redirection to **www.yourdomain.com/customer/account/login/**

**Inherited the block in cms home page:**

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" template="Magento_Customer::home_login.phtml"}}
```

I also tried other ways like showing the login section using adding in **cms_page_view.xml** layout

The code added in the **cms_page_view.xml**

```
<container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="Magento_Customer::newcustomer.phtml"/>
        </container>
```

This also behaving as same. When entering invalid credentials it redirects to **www.yourdomain.com/customer/account/login/**

Please give the solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Regards,
Sabareesh

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gagan, but I tired this also, the same action is happening when entering the invalid credentials.

Comment: I think you will need to override login post controller - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179636/magento-2-override-the-cutomer-account-loginpost-controller

Comment: I had a doubt in that, we can use the plugin structure in above link without changing the controller page vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost iam using the default LoginPost functionality

Comment: Yes, Plugin should be created. The verified answer uses Plugin only